# Acer Aspire P236HL, DVI-D to HDMI female

Tags: hdmi, dvi, acer-aspire, ps3, display-adapter

I bought an adapter that adapts HDMI to DVI. I connected my PS3's HDMI output to it and connected the DVI side to [my acer monitor](http://www.support.acer.com/acerpanam/MONITOR/2010/Acer/P236HL/P236HLsp2.shtml).

This fails to work, even after I reset the video controls on my PS3. I even switched the HDMI sides.

I wonder if I need a technician to help or if I need to get another graphics card.

This is a link to a similar adaptor: [link with picture](http://www.amazon.ca/StarTech-com-HDMIDVIFM-DVI-D-Video-Adapter/dp/B000GE9XRQ/ref=sr_1_14?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1344037020&sr=1-14). It is not exactly the same but its the same adapter from the inside just not the exact one I have.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Where does the Acer Aspire fit into this?  2) Does the monitor understand DVI-D (purely digital DVI, which is the likely output of the convertor) or does it expect an analog signal via DVI-I?

Comment: the screen series is part of aspire i belive and um on the nametag right over the input it says DVI-D in

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I have a friend with an 'Acer Aspire' laptop and I wrongly assumed you tried to use that in addition to the Xbox and the monitor. - I looked at the specs and it indeed understands DVI-D (digital only). Which should match with the signal coming from your HDMI source (which is basically DVI-D + copy protection scheme + audio)

Comment: so what your saying is that everything is fine its just the adapter i guess, HA i dont really care because these are really cheap i think the screws are a reason why i cant do it perfectly because the new one seems like a well fit